# Why do I get undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass when using Sorcery authentication in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorcery

I’m trying to fix an authentication issue in a Rails app.

When a user (called a member) signs up, the following error is thrown:

> undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass

this is in my sessions_controller.rb...

```
def create
 @member = login(params[:email], params[:password])
  if @member.save
   session[:member_id] = @member.id
   auto_login(@member)
   redirect_to root_path, notice: "hi #{@member.name}."
  else
   flash.now.alert = "login fail."
   render :new
  end
end
```

and this is in my members_controller.rb...

```
def create
 @member = Member.create(member_params)
 if @member.save
   auto_login(@member)
   redirect_to profile_path(current_member)
 else
   render 'new'
 end
end
```

Why would @member be nil?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on you members_controller:

```
def create
 @member = Member.new(member_params)
 if @member.save
   auto_login(@member)
   redirect_to profile_path(current_member)
 else
   render 'new'
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this happens when a user **signs in**, because I see a problem there. Such user was not found. **`login` does not change the account and can surely return `nil`** if such account is not found: either because of **non-existent email** or **wrong password**. That's why [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/283-authentication-with-sorcery?view=asciicast) checks not `user.save` (why even `save` an unchanged entity?), but just `user` (in case it's `nil`, it jumps to `else`):

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = login(params[:email], params[:password], params[:remember_me])
    if user
      redirect_back_or_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Email or password was invalid."
    end
  end
end
```

Your use of `save` in sign up process is odd as well. `create` passes the user object for the database to save right away, and you're saving it, again. You should use `new` instead, that only creates a Ruby object to fill with initial parameters - and then to save.

However, you can't just use `@m = M.create(...)` and `if @m`, because if `create` fails to validate parameters, a "candidate" object is still returned, so it will always be `true`.

```
def create
  @member = Member.new(member_params)
  if @member.save
    auto_login(@member)
    redirect_to profile_path(current_member)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

So... to sum up: [read this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/283-authentication-with-sorcery?view=asciicast) and keep your code close to snippets provided there until it works and you're able to trace when it breaks.